# "note that "an hour" with me tends to go pretty far" means that he usually needs more than an hour or less than hour?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am contacting a consultor in a particular area, and he has the mentioned phrase in his website, what does he want to express?

thanks in Advance

Comment: It might depend on what the previous sentences are. Assuming he charges his clients by the hour, he _probably_ means that he can fit a lot of topics into an hour-long consultation.

Comment: @KateBunting - that's how I would interpret it. He is saying, among other things, that he is efficient, does not waste time, and that most clients find that they get a comprehensive and attentive amount of service from the time they are billed for.

Comment: [go far](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/go-far): "to be sufficient or last long"

Comment: Yest it **is** ambiguous... but if the contractor is making this a selling-point, it likely means you could a lot accomplished in just an hour's consultation, *or* that the time might be extended a few minutes, *gratis*, for the base fee.

Comment: Please clean up your question and show some effort on your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Saying something "goes a long way" or "goes far" can mean that it accomplishes a lot. A particularly common use of this is in the phrase "*a little [of something] goes a long way*", which means that only a small amount of something is needed or has a great effect.

By saying that an hour with him "goes pretty far" he means that more will be accomplished in one hour than you might expect, or might be accomplished in the same time with someone else.